# Mathematica Code Involving For Loops Not Completing All Iterations

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, warning-messages

First of all, thank you for taking the time to read this. I'm working on a portion of code related to the genetic algorithm that is not producing the expected results. What the code is supposed to do is take a list of lists with binary bits, in this case `c = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}`, and change the elements within the sub-lists to either ones or zeros depending on what's given. So, in the case of the list `c`, when fed into the code, it should yield `{{0,1}, {0,0}}`. So I created a code involving two nested `For` loops. After some testing, I've come to realize it's only changing the first element in `c` (`{1, 0}`), but not the second (`{1, 1}`) and returns {`{0, 1}, {0, 1}}` instead of `{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}`. I've been trying for some time now to correct this, but so far I've been unsuccessful. I was hoping I could get some help here. The code is as follows:

```
    c = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}};
    Mutation1[c_] := Module[{d = c},
    MutatedSet = {}; (*This will be used to Append the new lists later*)

    For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++,

       (*This For Loop should take {1,0} AND 
       {1,1} the apply the rest of the code, but only does 
       this for the first element, {1,0}*)

       position = d[[i]];
       length = Length[position];

       For[i = 1, i <= length, i++,
          location = position[[i]];
          If[location == 0,
           Mutated = ReplacePart[position, i -> 1];
           ,
           Mutated = ReplacePart[position, i -> 0];
          ];
          position = Mutated;
        ];
       MutatedSet = Append[MutatedSet, position];
      ];
     MutatedSet = Append[MutatedSet, position];
     Print[MutatedSet];
    ];
```

Thanks again in advance for the help. It is very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 2) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 3) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `For` does not localize the variable `i`, therefore when the inner `For` loop runs out, the condition for the outer loop also fails and evaluation ceases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `For` loops are almost always unnecessary in Mathematica, but I'll address that towards the end of the answer. Don't miss the link at the end!

First of all, here are the corrections to the code keeping to your style:

```
Mutation1[c_] := Module[{d = c}, MutatedSet = {};

   For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++,

    position = d[[i]];
    length = Length[position];

    For[j = 1, j <= length, j++, location = position[[j]];
     If[location == 0, Mutated = ReplacePart[position, j -> 1];, 
      Mutated = ReplacePart[position, j -> 0];];
     position = Mutated;];

    MutatedSet = Append[MutatedSet, position];];
   Print[MutatedSet];];
```

You need different names for iterators in the two `For` loops. When you correct that, you get `{{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}` as output, because you had an extra unnecessary `MutatedSet = Append...` at the end of the `Module`.

There are still some issues with your function, however.

- You use `Module` which is a nice way to localize variables, yet the only local variable for this `Module` is `d`. Upon execution it creates several global variables, namely, `i`, `j` (in my corrected example), `length`, `position`, `MutatedSet`, `location`, `Mutated`.
- The function returns no output. It simply prints the value of `MutatedSet` as a side effect, but if you have something like `f[g[Mutation1[somelist]]]`, it will evaluate to `f[g[Null]]` which is probably not useful.

Let's address these issues.

```
Mutation1[c_] := 
  Module[{d = c, MutatedSet = {}, i, j, length, position, location, Mutated},

   For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++, 

    position = d[[i]];
    length = Length[position];

    For[j = 1, j <= length, j++, location = position[[j]];
     If[location == 0, Mutated = ReplacePart[position, j -> 1];, 
      Mutated = ReplacePart[position, j -> 0];];
     position = Mutated;];

    MutatedSet = Append[MutatedSet, position];];
   MutatedSet];
```

Nextly, all of these extra variables that are `position`, `length`, `location` are way too redundant, you're creating copies of several parts of the initial list. Also, you can do all the `ReplacePart`s to the initial list, but even better is to reassign the relevant parts of the list. Here's a simplification of the code, staying with `For` loops for the time being:

```
Mutation1[c_] := Module[{d = c, i, j},

   For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++,

    For[j = 1, j <= Length[d[[i]]], j++,
      If[d[[i, j]] == 0, d[[i, j]] = 1;, d[[i, j]] = 0;];
      ];
    ];
   d];
```

Much simpler. Now you're using `For` loops to iterate over the atomic elements of a list of lists apply the `If` operation to each element, which directly re-`Set`s the value of each element, rather than creating a copy of the sublist, then redefining the sublist as a list on which `ReplacePart` had worked, then appending it to an empty list... (my head's spinning, trying to describe this).

Finally, the good folks at Wolfram acknowledged long ago, that working with arrays is a very common thing and creating `For` loops every damn time to do this is tedious (when will C and such evolve to this thinking, huh?) and gave us the `Map` function.

Take your `If[...]` function, which is what's doing all the work here and map it to your list at level 2:

```
Mutation1[c_] := Map[If[# == 0, 1, 0]&, c, {2}]
```

I leave it to other contributors to suggest a simplification to the `If` function, as I imagine, you might have something more complex in mind, than applying `Not` to a list of boolean values.

**Please read up on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/26956) as well.**

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much! I'm not much of a programmer which I'm sure is evident. I cannot thank you enough for this!

Comment: This is a very nice, straightforward discussion of how to make existing code better and how to make the transition from procedural programming to Mathematica-style functional programming. +1

Comment: @march Thanks. Y'know, as soon as I wrote up this answer I went to google and *again* started looking for queries such as "why is Map not present in C" and such. Are there any programmers in other languages around that know, why everything is done via `For` loops everywhere else STILL in the XXI century???